# how to call header image while converting site html to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, header, wordpress-theming, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I am converting an HTML website to a WordPress site and don't know how to call the header image in the header. Also, I want a unique header image on each category page. Is there a way to do it without a plugin?[Background image below header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40pWg.jpg)

```
<div class="ftcat-header">
        <div class="ftcat-header-image-wrap">
            <div class="ftcat-header-image-overlay"></div>
                                <div class="ftcat-header-image skip-lazy" style='background-image: url("<?php echo wp_get_upload_dir()['baseurl'] . '/2022/02/cuisine.jpg'; ?>");'></div>
                            <div class="ftcat-header-content">
                <h1 class="ftcat-header-title">
                    Cuisine - Revues Des Produits et Guides d'Achat                    </h1>
                <div class="ftcat-header-search">
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://ideadear.com/">
                        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search for the best product..." value="" name="s" />
                        <button type="submit" class="search-submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="ftcat-header-meta">
                                                                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'header image'?

Comment: Hey, edited my question look again @khalil